# Split vector polygon into multiple vector shapes?

Tags: sketch-app

I have a logo that I am designing and I want to create an SVG. I started with 2 polygons, but I need to remove one side of the polygon and then split the polygon into multiple trianges (for different colors). How can I achieve this in Sketch?

What I have:

[image]

What I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: Rather than divide the shape, draw triangles that form one side and duplicate + rotate that group until you have a hexagon.

Comment: @Joonas You should really post this as an answer, it seems like a good one.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create one part of the logo like this one. [image: 4 triangles for 1 section]

Create this one section with the 4 triangles and then repeat it to create the entire logo. Rotate each section so it can fit adequately and then change the colors of the triangles as you see fit.